# SQL Query extremely slow when including NOT LIKE or a current row reference in a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT   
    DateName(month, DateAdd(month, [sfq].[fore_quart_month], -1)) AS [Month],
    [sfq].[fore_quart_so_rev] AS [Sales Orders Revenue],
    [sfq].[fore_quart_so_mar] AS [Sales Orders Margin],
    [sfq].[fore_quart_mac_rev] AS [MAC Revenue],
    [sfq].[fore_quart_mac_mar] AS [MAC Margin],
    [sfq].[fore_quart_total_rev] AS [TOTAL Revenue],
    [sfq].[fore_quart_total_mar] AS [TOTAL Margin],
    (SELECT SUM([FORE].[Revenue])
     FROM [SO_Opportunity][SO]
     LEFT JOIN [SO_Type] ON [SO].[SO_Type_RecID] = [SO_Type].[SO_Type_RecID]
     LEFT JOIN [SO_Opportunity_Audit][soa] ON [so].[Opportunity_RecID] = [soa].[Opportunity_RecId]
     LEFT JOIN [SO_Opportunity_Audit_Value][soav] ON [soa].[SO_Opportunity_Audit_RecId] = [soav].[SO_Opportunity_audit_recid]
     LEFT JOIN [SO_Forecast_dtl] [FORE] ON [SO].[Opportunity_RecID] = [FORE].[Opportunity_RecID]
     WHERE ([SO_Type].[Description] NOT LIKE '%MAC%' AND [SO_Type].[Description] NOT LIKE '%Maint%')
       AND YEAR([soa].[last_Updated_utc]) = @p_year AND MONTH([soa].[last_updated_utc]) = [sfq].[fore_quart_month]
       AND [soav].[audit_value] LIKE '%Closed - Won%' AND [soav].[audit_token] = 'new_value'
       AND [so].[SO_Opp_Status_RecID] = 7) AS [Rev]
FROM 
    [authmanager2].[dbo].[sales_forecast_quarterly][sfq]
WHERE 
    [sfq].[fore_quart_year] = @p_year AND [sfq].[fore_quart_loc] = 'w'
ORDER BY 
    [sfq].[fore_quart_month]
```

The issue is that when including the `NOT LIKE` filters and the `[sfq].[fore_quart_month]` reference in the subquery, it runs incredibly slow (minutes), but if I remove the NOT LIKE filters or if I hard set the value instead of use the `[sfq].[fore_quart_month]` (which obviously means every calculation will use the wrong month except the one I hard coded), then the query runs in less than a second.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What indexes are on your table? How does your query plan look? There are a lot of expressions in here that can be rewritten to utilise an index if it exists. For example avoid putting expressions around fields as that can stop index utilisation. So for example use `[soa].[last_updated_utc] BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate`. Even if this doesn't suit your input parameters, try and it see if it improves performance

Comment: Firstly you actually have `INNER` joins in your subquery from `so_type`, `soa` and `soav`. Don't tangle query optimizer. `[sfq].[fore_quart_loc]` is the only link to the outer query. If you comment it then it is enough to execute subquery only once - of course it will be faster. Review your execution plan. `LIKE` starting with '%' is bad for performance same as conversions in predicates.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` queries with wild cards on both ends are very slow. Example: `%MAC%`

If you really need to search on that, consider creating a persisted computed boolean field and searching on that. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE SO_Type
ADD IsMac AS CASE WHEN [Description] LIKE '%MAC%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED
GO
```

OR

As an alternative, set ISMac whenever data is inserted

Answer (score 0):

Small tip: you can group by month and join subquery to main datasource in `from` clause. This will let (which is not *must*) server perform subquery only once. And please note my comment above.

```
...
FROM [authmanager2].[dbo].[sales_forecast_quarterly][sfq]
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT SUM([FORE].[Revenue]) as [Revenue], MONTH([soa].[last_updated_utc]) as [Month]
     FROM [SO_Opportunity][SO]
     INNER JOIN [SO_Type] ON [SO].[SO_Type_RecID] = [SO_Type].[SO_Type_RecID]
     ...
     GROUP BY MONTH([soa].[last_updated_utc])
) rev on rev.[Month] = [sfq].[fore_quart_month]
```